# Why does usb drives autmount only for pi?

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, hard-drive, mount

Attached usb drives are automatically mounted in `/media/pi/`

What makes that they automount in **that** directory ?

Obviously this is configured somewhere.. What would be the way to customize this ?

**EDIT : please do not explain how to mount devices !**

Comment: Ah yes, to manually mount and unmount HDDs, see Appendix A, Part D of my answer to this question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100353/can-the-3b-power-two-usb-ssd-drives

Comment: @tlfong01 **Very** funny :(

Comment: Possible reasons: (1) that directory is default, (2) someone did that for you. I agree there is configuration somewhere. The configuration file (a) says where is the default, (b) disables or enables auto mounting.  I only know how to mount or unmount. and how to auto mount on boot..  I don't know where is the config file. Perhaps it is the /boot/config.txt  My apologies.

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. What directories to use in Linux is standardized in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard(FHS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). This also includes `/media/`. To be compliant you should not change it.

Comment: @Ingo I know that this standardized, but this not explains why automount mounts specifically in /media/pi/ and **not** in /media/myadmin/ /media/root/ /media/user/ etc.

Comment: You should elaborate your question about this and ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/