# Raspberry 3+ b and two external usb drives: lack of current

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, hard-drive

I've encountered the following problem: when I connect 1 external usb hdd to my Pi, everything works fine. But when I connect second one with the same characteristics, both drives are not usable. I believe the problem is with drives' power consumption: each hard drive draws 1A from the USB port and as far as I understand raspberry pi3+ provides 1.2A to **all the four usb-ports** and this is maximum current available.

Is there a way to solve this problem (my current sata-USB cases DOES NOT have an external power supply, but if they had, would this help)? Ideally I'd like to connect four drives, but even two would be cool.

Comment: My answer to the following question might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103784/can-a-raspberry-pi-4-power-an-external-hd

Comment: Use an external powered hub.

Comment: yeap. usb-hub with external power supply does the trick, thanks.
(I thougth those things were cheap but they are actually not. ~30 bucks for one)

Comment: Please make an answer for the solution and accept it after two days. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by connecting all the USB HDDs through the usb-hub with external power supply.