# Using USB hub to power external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb-hub

My Raspberry Pi can't produce enough power for WD external drive. I see that people recommend using a USB hub.
My WD hard drive has only one input. If I connect it to a USB hub, how do I connect the drive to the Raspberry itself?
Are all USB ports in the hub connected?

Comment: These might help: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103784/can-a-raspberry-pi-4-power-an-external-hd, (2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100353/can-the-3b-power-two-usb-ssd-drives. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Some USB hubs come with a port to connect to the host device, and a power cable that plugs into an outlet to power all the USB devices separate from the host device. Many USB 2.0 hubs use this, as USB 2.0 can only supply 0.5 amps. You can probably find such a hub on amazon for USB 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a powered USB hub, which comes with an external power supply. You would then connect the hub to one of USB ports on the Pi and the drive to the hub.