# Samsung MZ-76E250B/EU 860 EVO for raspberry pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, memory

I just bought my first raspberry pi and would love to attach an SSD. In search of good value for money, I came across [this drive](https://www.amazon.de/Samsung-MZ-76E250B-EU-interne-schwarz/dp/B078WQJXNF/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?creativeASIN=B07822P8JY&dchild=1&imprToken=wGNba4CN6Ova1RdefHaDVg&keywords=Samsung%20860%20EVO%20SSD%20500GB%20-%20mSATA%20Internal%20Solid%20State%20Drive%20with%20V-NAND%20Technology%20%28MZ-M6E500BW%29&linkCode=g13&linkId=ec373cb2f1d7a5c0e214af2cdd427c08&qid=1587022529&sr=8-1-fkmr1) from Samsung. Does someone already have experience with it? I am particularly unsure about the power supply.

Comment: Of all HDDs / SSDs I own, I haven's seen a single one which wouldn't work with a Pi.

Comment: I have been using a couple of SamSung T5 500G/1T SSDs for about one year.  So far so good, and I am loving it: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100353/can-the-3b-power-two-usb-ssd-drives. Cheers.

Comment: PS - My SSDs are USB but yours is SATA. I remember I once used SATA SSD for my evil WinPC and found it good. But I don't know how to connect a SATA SSD to Rpi, it might be hard to do so. :( Anyway, good luck and cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a 860 EVO 500GB works for me at least on Raspbian buster, Pi 4 with this USB 3.0 to SATA adapter  https://www.amazon.co.uk/ELUTENG-External-Support-Adapter-Compatible-Black/dp/B06XCV1W97/&qid=1587037480&sr=8-2.  No additional power needed, I'm using the official universal micro USB power supply.